# combine Autocomplete UI 1.8.16 and Autocomplete 1.0.2 plugin

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Autocomplete UI 1.8.16 and Autocomplete 1.0.2 plugin issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794341/autocomplete-ui-1-8-16-and-autocomplete-1-0-2-plugin-issue)

I am stuck up with a conflict between Autocomplete UI 1.8.16 and Autocomplete 1.0.2 plugin.

Any leads on how to combine these two?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more details and provide an example of the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: @Craig : Could you please follow the below thread for more clarity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794341/autocomplete-ui-1-8-16-and-autocomplete-1-0-2-plugin-issue.

Comment: This is the same as your other question. Please don't post duplicate questions (try offering a bounty instead).

Answer (score 0):

it is because both plugins have some functions that have same name. try to rename some conflict functions.

Answer (score 0):

The two autocomplete functions might conflict within the jquery namespace

try something like this:

```
<script src="jquery"></script>
<script src="plugin1"></script>
<script>
$p1 = $
$ = $p1.sub();
</script>
<script src="plugin2"></script>
```

Then use $p1() for the first plugin and $ everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Issue is still there and i am unsure on how to use $p1() on the JS which i have written for autocomplete UI 1.8.16 ?